# User specific content

Tags: users

Is it possible to show specific content or an entry for an individual user?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

*A logged in user make a request to receive information on a particular service. An administrator then reviews the request and creates an entry specific for that user - whatever is contained within that entry is then displayed on the users dashboard for them to view.*

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it truly unique content per user?  Or is it structured where the majority of the content is the same with some user specific variables swapped out?

Comment: The content that a user sees will be specific to them, but the content will already exist within the CMS and will be reused across users. Essentially, there will be a list of options written as entries in the CMS, when a user makes a request, what they ask for will determine what options they are presented with. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hrm... kinda? How are you organizing the entries to know how to grab for a user? Via categories? Or via different sections? Basically once you have a user, what's the logic to grab entry A vs. entry B for them?

Comment: Here's an example - Say it was a site that allowed you to find a tradesman. The logged in user enters their requirements for a job - these preferences are then manually checked (so this doesn't need to be linked to anything). Once they've been checked, a list of relevant tradesmen would be displayed to them in their dashboard. I'm just trying to work out whether its feasible and if so, the best approach to take.

Comment: Got it... that makes more sense.  Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example in your comments, a simple solution would be to create a "Potential Jobs" Entry field and assign it to the Users field layout.

Whoever is doing the manually checking to find a match between tradesmen and clients would assign entries to that field that match the requirements.

The front-end user's dashboard would check that field to see if it has any entries in it and display them to the user.

You could probably get more elaborate with a Category field (that had Entry fields in it) if you want to group by more fine-grained details.

Comment: Ah okay, that could work. And in the instance that a user posted another job request, how would you show multiple instances?

Comment: Maybe a Matrix field on the user with entry fields on that.